# Returning value from child process to parent process using exit() and wait() in C

Tags: linux, fork, ipc, wait, exit

The value of `status` is not returned correctly from the child to the parent process.

```
#include<stdio.h>
#include<unistd.h>
#include<sys/types.h>
#include<sys/wait.h>
#include<stdlib.h>
#include<string.h>
#define BUF_SIZE 200
int main(void){
pid_t pid;
int status=6;
char buf[BUF_SIZE];
pid=fork();
if(pid){
    sprintf(buf,"Value in parent process is %d\n",status);
    write(1,buf,strlen(buf));
    wait(&status);
    sprintf(buf,"Value returned from child process is %d\n",status);
    write(1,buf,strlen(buf));
}
else if(pid==0){
    status++;
    sprintf(buf,"Returning %d..\n",status);
    write(1,buf,strlen(buf));
    exit(status);
}
return 0;
}
```

The output of the code is :

```
Value in parent process is 6
Returning 7..
Value returned from child process is 1792
```

Where  is `1792` coming from? Why is this value not `7`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Because the man page continues...

> ```
>    If status is not NULL, wait() and waitpid() store status information in
>    the int to which it points.  This integer can  be  inspected  with  the
>    following  macros  (which take the integer itself as an argument, not a
>    pointer to it, as is done in wait() and waitpid()!):
>
>    WIFEXITED(status)
>           returns true if the child terminated normally, that is, by call‐
>           ing exit(3) or _exit(2), or by returning from main().
>
>    WEXITSTATUS(status)
>           returns  the  exit  status  of  the child.  This consists of the
>           least significant 8 bits of the status argument that  the  child
>           specified  in  a  call to exit(3) or _exit(2) or as the argument
>           for a return statement in main().  This macro should be employed
>           only if WIFEXITED returned true.
> ```